# Image loop is not working in react js?

Tags: reactjs

Images loop is not working. loop is working, but shows the string data a,b,c not the image source file. How can i show the images?

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Image.css';

export default class Imgs extends Component {
    render() {

        const names = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
        for (let i = 0; i < this.props.level; i++) {
            names.push(<img src={require("./icons/"+names+".jpg")} alt="" className="img-responsive" key={i} />  );
        }
        return (
            <div>
                <div className="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                {names}
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is images? what is this.props.level?

Comment: Do you have installed module in webpack for bundling images with jpg extensions? I think for images like this you need to put them inside variable using require first and than you can use them in React without the help of webpack.

Comment: no I have not installed

Comment: (sorry I have misinterpreted your question in my answer)

Comment: @Dan, I don't think you have. It seems to me that your answer was good and that it would work.

Comment: I've undeleted it, but I'm confused by `this.props.level`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to *map* the original array, rather than push to it:

```
  const names = ['a', 'b', 'c'];
  const imgs = names.map(function(name, i) {
    return <img src={require("./icons/"+ name +".jpg")} alt="" className="img-responsive" key={i} />  
  });

  return (<div>{imgs}</div>);
```

It's also unclear why you looped from 0 to this.props.level, but I hope this answer offers you some guidance.

Also, as Lazar mentioned in a comment, you'll need to have a way for Webpack to handle your .jpg files, such as the `file-loader` loader.

Comment: Error: Cannot find module './a,b,c.jpg'. showing this error

Comment: See `require("./icons/"+ name +".jpg")` instead of `require("./icons/"+ names +".jpg")` (I copied a typo from your question).